# How to print one result from function but store others

Tags: r, function

Consider this made up function:

```
Made_up <- function(x) {
one <- x 
two <- x + 1
three <- x + 2
}
```

How can I have the function only print the result of the object three and store the other variables to be called when I write

```
  answer <- Made_up(1)

  answer$....
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
Made_up <- function(x) {
one <- x 
two <- x + 1
three <- x + 2
print(three)
invisible(list(one=one, two=two, three=three))
}
```

Comment: It still prints out the contents of the list to the console. I want it to only print three and hide the list.

Comment: use `invisible(list(...))`

Comment: you're right @rawr. Added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vasily A's answer, you could use `return` and store the results from the function in `answer`.

```
Made_up <- function(x) {
  one <- x 
  two <- x + 1
  three <- x + 2
  print(three)
  return(list(one=one, two=two, three=three))
}

answer <- Made_up(1)
answer$one

[1] 1
```